# How to fire click event after bottom sheet close

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to fire the click event of the `<input type="file" #fileInput>'` after closing the `MatBottomSheet`

```
@ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput: ElementRef;
const bottomSheetRef = this.bottomSheet.open(DetailBottomSheet, {
  ariaLabel: 'Upload image'
});

bottomSheetRef.afterDismissed().subscribe(result => {
  let event = new MouseEvent('click', { bubbles: true });
  this.fileInput.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(event);
})
```

The event is working in firefox but when I try this on chrome the event is not firing. any idea why is this happening?

I'm really stuck in here, Please help.